# Is there an easy way to incorporate a java applet in an ASP.NET page?

Tags: java, asp.net, applet

I have a java applet that I would like to include in my ASP.NET page.  The applet works on a regular old HTML page.  When I try to include the applet in my ASP.NET page however, Java appears to start up (it shows the Java logo and the spinny blue circle), but an exception occurs for my main class:

```
load: class com.myclass.Main.class not found. 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myclass.Main.class
```

I am putting the applet in the page with the following code -

```
<applet
 code="com.xyz.Main.class"
 width="500"  height="500"
 archive="MyJar.jar"
>
    <param name="aParam" value="SomeValue"/>
</applet>
```

Note, this is exactly the same tag that I use to put the applet into a plain HTML page.  I'm guessing that the reason for the class not found exception is that when ASP compiles the page it puts it somewhere else?  If so, where?  Note that I still have not actually deployed this page to a web server, it's just running locally on my development machine.

Comment: "Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"  Excuse me for misplacing a space

Comment: "load: class com.myclass.Main.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myclass.Main.class"

Comment: Thank you. :-) Earlier comments deleted, edited CNFE into question.  ..And now I actually look at it, it made me realize that the `.class` addition in the `code` attribute is not needed, the fully qualified class-name of `com.xyz.Main` will work (or fail) just as well.  It is obviously not the real problem here (it is down to the code-base, as already mentioned by Paul).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply specify an absolute URI/oath to your applet with the [codebase attribute](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/special/applet.html)? That way you would not have to worry about the vagaries of relative pathing of different systems.

Also [see here for a longer explanation](http://www.iam.ubc.ca/guides/javatut99/applet/appletsonly/html.html). Excerpt:

**Specifying the Applet Directory**

By default, a browser looks for an applet's class and archive files in the same directory as the HTML file that has the  tag. (If the applet's class is in a package, then the browser uses the package name to construct a directory path underneath the HTML file's directory.) Sometimes, however, it's useful to put the applet's files somewhere else. You can use the CODEBASE attribute to tell the browser in which directory the applet's files are located:

```
    <APPLET CODE=AppletSubclass.class CODEBASE=aURL
            WIDTH=anInt HEIGHT=anInt>
    </APPLET>
```

If aURL is a relative URL, then it's interpreted relative to the HTML document's location. By making aURL an absolute URL, you can load an applet from just about anywhere -- event from another HTTP server.

Comment: I tried setting the codebase to the absolute directory that the jar file resides(ie - "c:\aDirectory\"), but that did not work.  I'm currently trying to run this page off of my development machine, it has not been deployed to a real web server yet (nor do I even have one).  This is because the page that i'm working on is part of a quick & dirty proof of concept page.

EDIT - And when I say that didn't work, I really mean a little green "picture" icon appeared in the top left corner of where the applet should be, but I do not get the error message

Comment: The codebase has to be a URL/URI and not a local machine path. Think about it this way: It is something that a browser in another country needs to be able to open... therefore it has to be a URL.

Comment: Like I said above, I have nowhere to put the .jar, thus the using the relative path.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a simple Java Applet.
2. Create a default web application.
3. Copy the Applet.class file to the web application folder.
4. Add a default user control to the web application.
5. Add the following HTML code in the user control.

> 

```
 <applet name="applet" code="applet.class" width="640" height="480" archive="applet.jar" 
    >     <param name="foreground" value="FFFFFF"/>
    >     <param name="background" value="008080"/>
    >     <param name="label" value="This string was passed from the HTML host."/>    </applet>
```

1. Build and run the web application

   And don't forget to add java.policy.applet.
   cheers, :)